# Question about lyrics of a A. C. Reed song

Tags: blues

During 1:33-1:40 in the song *help me spending my gold*, what is ac reed singing? Is he saying

> where Im all dressed up and I aint got no place to go

?
Here is the link to the song:

http://youtu.be/-MnYNx6J_x8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lyric is nearly correct, he's actually saying:

> Well, I'm all dressed up, ain't got no place to go

"All dressed up and [no place / nowhere] to go" is a common American idiom meaning to be ready for something that hasn't materialized.